# How to start Ubuntu-touch in kiosk mode without lightdm

Tags: ubuntu-touch, openbox, kiosk, mir

I've bought an Aquaris M10 and I'd like to use it as kiosk. I found a tuto on internet to disable standard desktop manager and just open my app with openbox.
[Tuto](https://thepcspy.com/read/converting-ubuntu-desktop-to-kiosk/)

The problem is that ubuntu touch use Mir and openbox is not present in repos. Does someone know how to do it with my tablet ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "using as kiosk" ?

Comment: It means I only wan one app at boot like firefox without all unity gesture. As you can see in my link, the author do it overriding window manager and launch an openbox with the browser.